# C code about the pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My goal is to read a file, and save each elements in this file into a new array..

```
rewind(fp); ii = 0; while (!feof(fp)) {
    ii ++;
    fscanf(fp, "%s\n", filename_i);
    fp_i = fopen(filename_i, "r");
    if (fp_i == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open input file %s \n", filename_i);
        exit(1);
    }
    filename_ii[ii] = filename_i;
    printf("%s, %d\n", filename_ii[ii],ii);
    fclose(fp_i);

}


printf("a %s %d\n",filename_ii[9],DataSize[2]);
printf("a %s %d\n",filename_ii[1],DataSize[2]);
```

In while() function, my output is each elements, but I don't know why the last two printf() returns the same results, i.e, it seems like both filename_ii[1] and filename_ii[9] point the last element in the file. Does anyone have ideas about what's wrong in my code？ Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy a string. Change:

```
filename_ii[ii] = filename_i;             // this just assigns a pointer -
                                          // it doesn't actually copy a string
```

to:

```
strcpy(filename_ii[ii], filename_i);      // copy the *contents* of `filename_i`
                                          // to `filename_ii[ii]`
```

This assumes of course that the `filename_ii` array has been correctly initialised and is not just an array of dangling `char *` pointers (not possible to tell from the code as currently posted in the question).

Note that if `filename_ii` *is* just an array of uninitialised `char *` pointers then you can use [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to handle the memory allocation and copying all in one convenient function call. In which case you would change the line above to:

```
filename_ii[ii] = strdup(filename_i);     // allocate memory to `filename_ii[ii]` and
                                          // copy the *contents* of `filename_i`
                                          // to `filename_ii[ii]`
```

Comment: After changing to 'strcpy()', it still doesn't work out. I think maybe I didn't initialize the 'filename_ii' correctly. I used 'char *filename_ii[20]'.

Comment: As I said above: *This assumes of course that the `filename_ii` array has been correctly initialised and is not just an array of dangling `char *` pointers*. I've added to my answer above to cover this now.

Comment: After Changing to strdup(), it works out. Thank you very much! @Paul R

Comment: OK - don't forget to free() the memory when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using `feof()`/`fscanf()` like that, it's super-brittle and needlessly hard to get right.

Instead:

```
char line[1024]; /* or whatever makes you feel comfortable */
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
{
  size_t len = strlen(line);
  if(len == 1) /* Ignore blank lines. */
    continue;
  if(line[len - 1] == '\n')
    line[--len] = '\0'; /* Remove linefeed. */
  if(access(line, R_OK) == 0)
    strcpy(filename_ii[ii++], line);
}
```

This:

1. Uses [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read in a whole line.
2. Uses [`access()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) to check if the file can open. Note that this kind of checking is always prone to race-conditions.
3. Uses `strcpy()` to copy the filename, assuming `filename_ii[]` is a properly set up array.

Comment: Why I get this error "read-only variable is not assignable" for ' line[--len] == '\0';' @unwind

Comment: How to set up 'filename_ii[]' properly? I still haven't work out.

Comment: @user2760099, see updated code. Should be an assignment (`=`) not an equality test (`==`) in that line.

Comment: Ah, drop the `const` when declaring `len`.